# Resize and save image in disk not saving the correct file Dimensions

Tags: swift, macos

i'm working on a macOS application and, I'm trying to resize image and save it with the new size Dimensions, but I'm facing an issue, after saving the image and looking for the Dimensions, I'm found it saved but not with the new Dimensions. for example, I have an image (72 x 72) and in my code, I resized it to (35 x 35), if I printed the width and height from code it shows (35 x 35) but after saving the file, in details I find the dimensions back to (72 x 72)

here is the details for the original image I'm importing to my code
[image]

and here is my code

```
      let targetSize = NSSize(width: 35, height: 35)
  let newImageResized = newImages.resized1(to: targetSize)
  print(newImageResized?.width)
  img2.image = newImageResized
       let fileName = "newImage"
       do {
           let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
           let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).png")
         if (newImages.pngData) != nil
  {
   let _ = try newImages.pngWrite(to: fileURL)

        }
       } catch { }
```

and here is the exitintion for NSImage

```
import Cocoa
extension NSImage {
      func resized1(to newSize: NSSize) -> NSImage? {
          if let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(
              bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: Int(newSize.width), pixelsHigh: Int(newSize.height),
              bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false,
              colorSpaceName: .calibratedRGB, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0
          ) {
              bitmapRep.size = newSize
              NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
              NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: bitmapRep)
              draw(in: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height), from: .zero, operation: .copy, fraction: 1.0)
              NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

              let resizedImage = NSImage(size: newSize)
              resizedImage.addRepresentation(bitmapRep)
              return resizedImage
          }

          return nil
      }
}
```

and here is a screenshot for the image details after saved
[image]

if anyone has an idea of how I can save this image with the correct Dimensions 
kindly help

Comment: "for example, I have an image (72 x 72) and in my code, I resized it to (35 x 35)"  You've started with an image of what!?  72 pixels times 72 pixels or 72 points x 72 points?  And you've ended with what?

Comment: i mean (72 x 72) pixels and  (35 x 35) pixels

Comment: Actually i'm trying to debug and i found there is a function called Copy

    func copy(size: NSSize) -> NSImage? {
        let frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        
        guard let rep = self.bestRepresentation(for: frame, context: nil, hints: nil) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let img = NSImage(size: size)
        
        img.lockFocus()
        defer { img.unlockFocus() }
        
         if rep.draw(in: frame) {
            return img
        }
        
         return nil
    }

Comment: the issue in defer { img.unlockFocus() } when debugger is stoping on it, it duplicate the size again

Comment: You're calling pngWrite on newImages - shouldn't that be on newImageResized? Otherwise you're just saving the original file.